# Ajax call to controller that returns an excel file stream is causing not well formed error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Our current web site has several html tables of data that can be sorted client side, which they would then like to export to an excel file. I am attempting to create generic methods that can handle any table data passed into the controller and create the file in memory only. I am just using a simple button click event to initiate an ajax call passing in a JSON object to the controller, as seen here:

```
  var convertedTable = JSON.stringify({ myTableArray: myTableArray });

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/TableToExcel',
    data: JSON.stringify({ myTableArray: myTableArray }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     dataType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    success: function (returnValue) {

        window.location = '/Reports/Download?file=' + returnValue;

    }
});
```

The controller is simple right now and returns the file fine when called directly by the browser.

```
    public FileResult Index(List<string[][]> tableData)
    {
        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample2");

        ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Sample 2";
        ws.Cells["A1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

        var stream = new MemoryStream(pck.GetAsByteArray());

        return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

I keep getting a not well formed error in FF debugger. Is this the correct way to handle this?

I am also thinking that a form would be the better way to go, but not sure if that would work since I need to process the table data first before submitting the form and need to use a POST to handle the JSON object.

Any suggestions on what would be the best way to handle this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone searching for the answer. 
It is you can **not** do it this way. 
I was actually trying to pass the file itself back. From what I have read and determined Ajax only accepts strings back. All the examples I came back to returned the saved file location not the file itself.